# PDO returns 0 instead of rowcount

Tags: php, pdo, rowcount

Only the first of SQL statements returns a valid result. Others return 0. I can't figure out why. What am I doing wrong?
Here is the code:

```
$year = htmlspecialchars($_POST['year']);
$ukupan_broj_servisa="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM services WHERE date BETWEEN '$year-01-01' AND '$year-12-31'";
$ukupan_broj_malih_servisa="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM services WHERE service_mali > '' AND date BETWEEN '$year-01-01' AND '$year-12-31'";
$ukupan_broj_velikih_servisa="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM services WHERE service_veliki > '' AND date BETWEEN '$year-01-01' AND '$year-12-31'";
$ukupan_broj_kola="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cars";
$stmtser = $pdo->prepare($ukupan_broj_servisa);
$stmtmali = $pdo->prepare($ukupan_broj_malih_servisa);
$stmtveliki = $pdo->prepare($ukupan_broj_velikih_servisa);
$stmtkola = $pdo->prepare($ukupan_broj_kola);
try {
    $stmtser->execute();
    $stmtmali->execute();
    $stmtveliki->execute();
    $stmtkola->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Došlo je do greške u bazi podataka. Molimo pokušajte kasnije ili kontaktirajte administratora.";
    echo $e;
    exit();
}
echo '
    <label id="brojvozila">'.$stmtkola->fetchColumn(0).'</label>
    <label id="brojservisa">'.$stmtser->fetchColumn(0).'</label>
    <label id="brojmalihservisa">'.$stmtmali->fetchColumn(0).'</label>
    <label id="brojvelikihservisa">'.$stmtveliki->fetchColumn(0).'</label>
';
```

Comment: There is no point in using prepared statements if you concatenate the values in the query string. It is not what prepared statements are for.

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem. I replaced it with $pdo->query(), same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. I reinstalled MySQL server and it worked.